# MAD results differ in pandas, scipy, and numpy

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scipy

I want to compute the [MAD (median absolute deviation)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_absolute_deviation) which is defined by

```
MAD = median(|x_i - mean(x)|)
```

for a list of numbers `x`

```
x = list(range(0, 10)) + [1000]
```

However, the results differ significantly using `numpy`, `pandas`, and an hand-made implementation:

```
from scipy import stats
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

print(stats.median_absolute_deviation(x, scale=1)) # prints 3.0

print(pd.Series(x).mad()) # prints 164.54

print(np.median(np.absolute(x - np.mean(x)))) # prints 91.0
```

What is wrong?

Comment: pd.Series().mad() gives you the Mean Absolute Deviation, and not the median absolute deviation you expect.

Comment: Oh damn it. :) What about the others?

Comment: the scipy.stats implementation is right on. Your hand made implementation needs to be changed as per answer by Mykola.

Comment: The last one should be `np.median(np.absolute(x - np.median(x)))`. And the first formula is wrong too.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The median absolute deviation is defined as:

```
median(|x_i - median(x)|
```

The method `mad` in Pandas returns the mean absolute deviation instead. You can calculate MAD using following methods:

```
x = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1000]

stats.median_absolute_deviation(x, scale=1)
# 3.0

np.median(np.absolute(x - np.median(x)))
# 3.0

x = pd.Series(x)
(x - x.median()).abs().median()
# 3.0
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You are right, although I think the naming is slightly confusing (at least to me). What about scipy?

Comment: Scipy must be OK.

Answer (score 1):

In pandas, MAD is actually '*mean* absolute deviation' and not '*median* absolute deviation'.

You can find the equation used in pandas here: https://www.skytowner.com/explore/pandas_dataframe_mad_method